# Chatbot .after() without function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, chatbot

I'm making a chatbot, and I figured out how to send a bot response based on a user's input, but I want to wait 2 seconds before the bot message sends. In order to do that with the .after() method, I would need a function to call. I tried a nested function initially but that didn't work.

I can't call the send() function because that is what sends the users input to the main conversation (text widget) and I don't want that to take 2 seconds to send each time.

Current code that works:

```
# gets message from user and sends to main chatroom 
def send(self):
    the_message = self.user.get()
    assign_user = '\n' 'You: ' + the_message
    self.chatroom.insert('end', assign_user, 'you')

    **# I need to be able to call the following if statement by a function name (to use the .after() method), but I need the previous lines of code to detect when a user sends something and what they said in the first place**
    if the_message != '' and '?' in the_message:
        bot_message = '\n' 'Sam: Thanks for your question(s)! Please type your email and I will get back to you ASAP.'
        self.chatroom.insert('end', bot_message, 'sam')
    elif the_message != '' and '?' not in the_message:
        bot_message = '\n' 'Sam: Thanks for your message! Please type your email and I will get back to you ASAP.'
        self.chatroom.insert('end', bot_message, 'sam')
```

Comment: If you want us to help you get your code working, we need to see *the code that doesn't work*, rather than working code that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Wherever you call `self.send()` after getting user input, call `xxx.after(2000, self.send)`  instead where `xxx` is any widget or the root window.